# How can I get the Caveman2Cosmos mod working?

Tags: technical-issues, civilization-4, civilization-4-beyond-the-sword

I downloaded and installed version 28 of the Caveman2Cosmos mod the other day, and am having trouble getting it to run. When I load the mod, Civilization closes down as normal, but never reappears. Eventually Windows tells me "Sid Meier's Civilization 4: Beyond the Sword has stopped working."

**System information:** I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit and have over 4GB of RAM still available when the crash occurs.

Here is the error text displayed when I show the problem details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: Civ4BeyondSword.exe
  Application Version:  3.1.3.1
  Application Timestamp:    48317e8a
  Fault Module Name:    CvGameCoreDLL.dll
  Fault Module Version: 3.1.9.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5105a233
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000d50c2
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 8485
  Additional Information 2: 84853502223d8164a31468861a7c3d71
  Additional Information 3: 096e
  Additional Information 4: 096e1bd0f1dc1c0a0e6c1d8ecc5c1361
```

If any more information is needed to pin down the problem, I'll be more than happy to edit it in.

Comment: Hmm... doing some more research it looks like a currently not-installed patch may fix this. I've got BtS 3.17 and there's a patch to bring it up to version 3.19. I'm downloading it now and will check back later. Also, I've previously attempted to install it from the game's built-in patching system to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mods in general, be sure your currently installed version of Civilization is compatible with the mod.

In this specific case, the Caveman2Cosmos mod did not work because Civilization IV: Beyond the Sword was not patched to [the latest Beyond the Sword version, 3.19](http://forums.civfanatics.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=12576).

The in-game patching has not worked for me on the three computers I've tried with it, but fortunately it is also possible to manually download and install [the v3.19 patch](http://www.firaxis.com/downloads/Patch/Civ4BeyondTheSwordPatch3.19.exe) from [the downloads section of Firaxis Games' website](http://www.firaxis.com/games/downloads.php). This worked like a breeze and I am now able to play the awesome C2C mod.